# Default argparse values

Tags: python

I have a script where the user can input two date values for a date range to run my script. If they don't input two values, I want my script to run with a default date range. How can I do this?

Right now this is what I have:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('start', type=str, help='Start date YYYY-MM-DD')
parser.add_argument('end', type=str, help='End date YYYY-MM-DD')
args = parser.parse_args()

start = args.start
stop = args.end

** if the two dates are invalid or not provided by user: ** 
start = '20220101'
stop = '20220416'
```

Comment: use `default=` arg for the `add_argument`

Comment: `parser.add_argument('end', type=str, help='End date YYYY-MM-DD', default='2022-10-05`)`

Comment: This gets tricky, as you can't get a default `start` without using the default `end`, as `myscript 20220805` will assume it was given a starting date.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the argument default

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('start', type=str, default='20220101', help='Start date YYYY-MM-DD')
parser.add_argument('end', type=str, default='20220416', help='End date YYYY-MM-DD')
args = parser.parse_args()

start = args.start
stop = args.end
```

Comment: Specifying a default argument isn't sufficient, You also need to use `nargs='?'`, as positional parameters are required by default.